# Facebook APP ID and Secret

Tags: facebook, key, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get a facebook app id and secret without verifying your account (for neither do I want to provide FB with credit card information nor do they list my mobile phone service provider for the country I live in) - or is there a way to run an FQL query on PHP without having and app id and secret?

For all I wanna do is to check whether the currently logged-in user likes my page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So are you asking about an app or a page?

Comment: Well, I need it for my page, but in order to execute the FQL via PHP, according to Facebook, I need an app to have an app id and secret in order to be able to create the facebook object for its PHP Graph API.

Comment: "Facebook Page" or a website page?

Comment: A website page with likes being counted for its own Facebook page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to run an FQL query on
>   PHP without having and app id and
>   secret?

No you can't. You need a valid FB App ID and Secret.

> Is there a way to get a facebook app
>   id and secret without verifying your
>   account

The answer is still no. You need to be a verified user to create an application on facbook.

Comment: another thing: for I am not yet a verified user and hence did not yet have the possibility to check... an FQL query, does it have to be run from http://apps.facebook.com or can I, having an app id and secret, run it even from my own server?

Comment: If you have an app ID and secret then you can run it from your own server. Using the graph api. But one person should authorize the app once and then save the access token and use it further more.

Comment: ok, thanks, can't wait to check it out ^^ (as soon as I have managed to verify my account... )